# Как отследить падения php и сократить время простоя?

Tags: nginx, php

Связка `php5-fpm + nginx, apache2` игнорируем
Периодически, от неожиданных нагрузок, php падает - сначала на сайте, который даёт нагрузку, потом на всех остальных; `ошибка 504 (timeout)`, затем `502 (bad gateway)`.
Через небольшой промежуток времени, он поднимается и всё работает как надо.в **`/var/log/php5-fpm.log`** отражается только процесс запуска и останова.

КАК отследить такие падения и сократить время простоя?
Есть мысль, что нужно как то проверять, насколько эффективно откликается 9000 порт, который слушает `fastcgi`, или отслеживать `504/502` ответ сервера и оперативно перезапускать сервис, или в другую сторону смотреть... не знаю =(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй увеличить количество коннектов везде где это целесообразно. Также посмотри, что в момент проблемы происходит в базе. Попробуй разобраться с php-логом, чтобы в него писалось что-то осмысленное о происходящем.